# Python-Change String in file and output all content with the new strings to a new file

Tags: file

i`m trying to scan for a string in all files under a directory and several sub directories , replace it , and when i preformed the replacement save it into a new file,
I managed to 
1) search for the string in all the files in the folder and sub folders , 
2) count the amount of appearances of the string 
3) create new files for those who had the string .

But for some reason the new files i get are empty , instead of containing the lines of the old files with the replaced string .

Here is my Code :

```
import os

parentDirectory = "E:\ProjectPython\Test"
oldString = "oldString"
newString = "newString"

if (os.path.isdir(parentDirectory)):
    for dirName,directories,files in os.walk(parentDirectory):
        for fileName in files:
            fullPath = os.path.join(dirName,fileName)
            with open(fullPath) as file:
                counter=0
                for line in file:
                    if line.__contains__(oldString) or line.__contains__(oldString.lower()):
                        counter=counter+1
                if counter>>0 :
                        with open(fullPath+".New","w") as newFile:
                            for line in file:
                                newFile.write(line.replace(oldString,newString))
                        print("File:"+fullPath+"\nStrings that were replaced:"+str(counter))

else:
    print(parentDirectory+"is missing!")
```

Comment: You've already read the entire file in the first `for line in file` loop; the second time you do it, there are no lines left to read.  Put `file.seek(0)` to rewind before the second loop.  Also, note that `line.__contains__(oldString)` is perverse - the double underscore methods are how special functionality is implemented, not how it is used.  That should be written `oldString in line`.

Comment: Thank you , the File.seek(0) helped , now i`m getting output in the new files